# list index out of range .what to do?

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop, if-statement

my code that takes a sequence of numbers and determines whether all the numbers are different from each other:

```
lst=[]
while True:
    num=input('enter:')
    if num=='done':
        break
    n=int(num)
    lst.append(n)
print(lst)
c=0
lst1=lst
print(lst1)
for i in lst:
    for j in lst1:
        if lst[i] == lst1[j]:
            c+=1
if c==1:
    print("true")
else:
    print("false")
```

the code is only working when if `(c==1)` is satisfied  otherwise it's showing that `list is out of index in line 14`

Comment: The *i* and *j* are values acquired via *input()*. They are not indexes. Thus it is possible that such values may exceed the bounds of your lists

Comment: You are iterating over the elements of `lst` and then try to index into the same list with the value of these elements. Suppose `lst` contains the value `1000`, that does not mean that `lst[1000]` exists. There are other semantic errors in your code.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find out if a list of integers contains only unique numbers then you can do this:

```
mylistofnumbers = [1,2,3]

if len(mylistofnumbers) == len(set(mylistofnumbers)):
  print('Unique')
else:
  print('Not unique')
```

The key to this is that a set can only contain unique values. Therefore, if the length of the set is the same length as the list then the list must contain only unique numbers